# Python querying mysql iteratively

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, mysql-python

I have a list of column names that I want to pull from a mysql database. It is good practice to loop through it and query each time?

When I do this, sometimes/randomly it seems to hang; when I restart the script, it hangs at different iterations. Was wondering whether this is bad practice to do in the first place before I continue trying to decipher what's the issue.

```
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pw', host='ip_here')
for i,j in enumerate(columnList):
   cursor.execute('SELECT `' + j + '` FROM `table_name`')
   iValues = cursor.fetchall()
   cursor.close
   if i == 0:
      extractedValues = iValues
   else:
      extractedValues = np.hstack((extractedValues, iValues))

cnx.close
```

Comment: Dont know who told you to loop through database. Its not a good idea. Fetchall all  the data needed local or in memory and loop through the fetched data. 200 items in the column means 400 trips to and back from the db verses just two.  This should clear up the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very odd to query individual columns one at a time, since you won't be able to relate the values in one column to another.  Unless your table is a grab-bag of unrelated data (not really records, i.e. your table is not at all normalized) this will remove all meaning from the data. If you're trying to deal with dynamic or variable columns, you could build a dynamic query string (append column name, comma, column name, comma ...) then execute that query.  I'm hard-pressed to think of scenarios where querying individual columns rather than rows/records is useful.

Comment: Thanks Chris for bringing this up; didn't think about it before. It makes more sense for me to have the current columns as rows and vice versa but unfortunately my data doesn't fit the current column limitations of innodb (since I would have over 20,000 columns). Guess I should switch to cassandra or so.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...not tested:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pw', host='ip_here')
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM database.`table_name`')
iValues = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close
cnx.close

#for i,j in enumerate(iValues):
#   if i == 0:
#      extractedValues = iValues
#   else:
#      extractedValues = np.hstack(())
extractedValues =  list(iValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this, it will get only the columns you need, each together in a single row with only one select:

```
  import mysql.connector
  import numpy as np

  cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pw', host='ip_here')

  cursor.execute('SELECT ' + ['`' + col + '`' for col in columnList].join(',') + ' FROM `table_name`')
  values = cursor.fetchall()

  # now values variable has the data in the columns you need
```

no need to `for` because of list comprehension, it will generate a single select like

```
  SELECT `COLa`, `COLb`, `COLc` FROM `table_name`;
```

and then execute it once and get the data in `values` variable

Comment: is there something to be improved in the answer? Why the downvote?